# photoshop render fibers and export as transparent background png

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

so I rendered fibres. really light ones. take a look

[image]

I want the fibres to stay and everything around them to be transparent
tried a bunch of things like changing levels, exposure, contrast etc 
but even then i cant seem to export it as a transparent png where fibres stay while the area around them becomes transparent

do I need to use something other than photoshop for this? 
or am I missing something here.

thanks a bunch 
love y'all

Comment: The Fiber Filter renders a black and white layer. As with *any* image, if you don't want the white, you need to remove it. There are a number of methods to removing the background from an image.

Comment: Other methods aren't that difficult, but looking at that one answer below and the slight white glow present in the result, I'd suggest a simpler method: **1.** Take brush tool **2.** Edit > make brush preset **3.** make sure you have black color selected and opacity is 100. You may want to resize the canvas or open a larger document. Brush somewhere in the document by clicking on once.

Comment: @qwexar, have you tried the process outlined in the answer? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the above image but the following steps should produce fibers on a transparent layers, showing what is underneath. I am adding an image which has a background half red half blue to show you the effect.

1. Add a white layer and apply the fibers filter
2. Switch to Channels panel and Ctrl-click on the RGB layer icon at the top
3. This will select the luminance information, you need to invert this, so press Ctrl-Shift-I
4. Switch back to the Layers palette
5. Now press Ctrl-J to create a new layer from the selection
6. Turn off the original fibers layer
7. Optionally, repeat step 2-3 on the fiber layer, add a new blank layer on top of everything, pick a color any color, fill the selection with that to have colored fibers. Instead of filling with the color, you can brush it where you want.
8. Optionally, lower the opacity to desired level if too strong

This will show fibers resting on the background

Optionally, if you like denser fibers showing, target the new layer you made in step 5 and press Ctrl-J to duplicate which will add more density.

Here is an image that shows the fibers on colored background:

[image]